# como usar o mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

gostaria de saber como que eu uso esse comando `mysql` no meu código pois estou tentando e nada não consigo fazer ele funcionar se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

código:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM produtos LIMIT $inicio, $totalProduto");
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli, $sql)){
              $id = $aux['id_produto'];
              $nome = $aux['nome'];
              $desc = $aux['descricao'];
              $preco = $aux['preco'];
              $categoria = $aux['categoria'];
              $img = $aux['img'];
              $tipo = $aux['type'];
              $size = $aux['size'];
```

Comment: E qual é o problema? E já vejo uma maluquice aí que as variáveis locais não batem com os nomes dos membros dos objetos. Até pode, mas não faz sentido. Outro problema é o uso do `$mysqli` como parâmetro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` recebe apenas um argumento que é o retorno de `mysqli_query()` e não a conexão.

Mude para:

```
 while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
```

Ao utilizar o estilo procedural do MySQLi em **QUASE** todas as funções o primeiro argumento é a conexão, `mysqli_fetch_*()` é um exceção dessa regra.

Veja a assinatura da função

> mixed mysqli_fetch_array ( mysqli_result $result [, int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH ] )

[Documentação - fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

[Documentação - lista de funções](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: vlw rray nao tinah percebido pra mim eu teria que passar a conexao junto vlw funciono

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, ao utilizar o estilo procedural do mysqli **QUASE** todas as funções o primeiro argumento é a conexão, `mysqli_fetch_()` é um exceção dessa regra :P

Comment: intendi. vlw cara